# LongListSelector JumpListStyle background binding not works

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am using longlistselector in my win phone 8 app. I have used ItemTemplate, GroupHeaderTemplate and JumpListStyle. For GroupHeaderTemplate I am using xaml

```
  <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="0 0 0 10">
              <Grid.Background>
                      <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding DataContext.ForegroundColor, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
              </Grid.Background>                                
         </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
```

This is working fine. But if I apply same to ItemTemplate for JumpListStyle than it does nothing. The only difference is in this case template is defining inside style.

```
  <phone:LongListSelector.JumpListStyle>                        
         <Style TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
              <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource JumpListDataTemplate}"/>                              
          </Style>
  </phone:LongListSelector.JumpListStyle>
```

Any suggestion, what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: What do you mean it does nothing? Take a screenshot. Whats your JumpListDataTemplate?

Comment: It's same as above GroupHeaderTemplate. Only Key is included as TextBlock.